# Enable of Bluetooth with BluetoothManager is not working

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to activate `BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)` on an Android Phone (currently using an emulator on Android Studio). I know that I can't use Bluetooth with an emulator, but even without it I'm still having some troubles here is the code.

My main problem is where the `bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` is located. I have added the `manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH` for it but even after doing so I can't seem to understand where I may have made a mistake.

```
    // Initializes Bluetooth adapter.
       @SuppressLint("NewApi")

          
   public final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
if  (bluetoothManager != null)
{
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
}

if  (bluetoothAdapter != null && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
{
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your issue, as you do not mention, what exactly doesn't work, but I expect that bluetooth is not turning on.

So here are the official android guides from Google:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#permissions

I think you're missing the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`, as well as the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, which is required for BLE if you're not using Device Companion Manager.

Please just follow the steps from the Links and it should work!

PS: Please have a look at correct spelling, grammar as well as on the format of the post and provide clear and concise information if you need help. It's not really easy to figure out what you need with the information provided.

Comment: Hello yes i've been using those guides already and had added both of the permission and i came on StackOverflow because i did not succeed to find the error

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?